# App Center can't locate android project if it's not at root level

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

I've setup a few app center android projects but they usually have the android project at the same level as the git root.

Now I have another project that is one level deeper than the git root. In this case app center says "We couldn’t find any Android projects in your branch."

Is there a setting where I could point app center towards the android project directory? I know I can shuffle the project around but I would rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I had a special character as part of a folder in the project. It was the danish letter Ø. After talking with the AppCenter engineers we have figured out that their script that was locating the project folder failed when encountering this special character. Replacing the 'Ø' with 'o' fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

In my case problem was solved by removing some Gradle scripts from `.gitirnore`:

```
/gradlew
/gradlew.bat
gradle-wrapper.jar
```

These files should be in your repository if you want App Center to find your project.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using recent version of android studio 4.0+. The build.gradle files have been restructured to display like this.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'}
```

Appcenter does not recognise this format. Change it to the old format like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply from: "../ktlint.gradle"
```

Comment: This was my issue. It's strange that AppCenter isn't in line with the latest Gradle guidelines.